# Change Text Size and color

Tags: android, text, fonts, andengine

I want to change the color and size of a text. I want to use only a single font for that. Is it possible?

Here is my code: Define font & Text

```
// for red color font
redFont = FontFactory.createFromAsset(activity.getFontManager(),
                fontTexture, activity.getAssets(), "YIKES__.TTF", 30, true,
                Color.parseColor("#EF522A"));
        redFont.prepareLetters("Score:1234567890 Sec Cash / Level"
                .toCharArray());
        redFont.load();

// for white color font
    ITexture whiteFontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(
                activity.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);

        whiteFont = FontFactory.createFromAsset(activity.getFontManager(),
                whiteFontTexture, activity.getAssets(), "YIKES__.TTF", 30, true,
                Color.WHITE);
        whiteFont.prepareLetters("Score:1234567890 Sec Cash / Level"
                .toCharArray());
        whiteFont.load();
```

and then initialize text and change size like:

```
gameOverText = new Text(0, 0,
            ResourcesManager.getInstance().whiteFont,
            "ABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
            ResourcesManager.getInstance().vbom);
    gameOverText.setPosition(45, 72);
//  gameOverText.setSize(490, 115);
    gameOverText.setText(gameOver);
```

and change the color like :

```
// define the color
pColor = new org.andengine.util.color.Color(255, 102, 51); 
gameOverText.setColor(pColor);
```

but I am not achieve the success. So close to below one.

[image]

Comment: I had issues with this way back when but can't remember the solution. It has to do with the alpha channel - looking at my code, to get a color other than white, I had to also set the alpha channel using this Color.argb(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue) - try that instead of your parseColor call

Answer (score 1):

This is old post and i hope you have already found answer but for those who still dont have idea how to do it you can try this. Changing size of font is rather simple. You can scale it using setScale methods of andengine.

```
gameOverText.setScale(0.1f); //Scales both X and Y
gameOverText.setScaleX(0.5f); //Scales X only
gameOverText.setScaleY(1.0f); //Scales Y only
```

There are other scaling methods which you can use based on your need. Also scale factor ranges from 0(min) to 1(max) value.

Finally, for color which took me whole day to figure out. Andengine font have setColor method for setting color but it only works if you set color object from **android.graphics.Color.rgb(255,223,0)** class. If used other color it just mask color and produce weird result than you have expected.

```
gameOverText.setColor(android.graphics.Color.rgb(255,0,0)); //For Red
```

Hope this help someone in future.

Answer (score -2):

Use `setTextColor()` or `setTextSize()` on the `TextView` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks mark. i am in AndEngine!!! not in android. that does support TextView.@Mark